# Access Redux store in getServerSideProps in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

I want to access my redux store in the getServerSideProps(); in my Next.js app. I want to have the user id which i'm storing in the Redux Store so i can preload user data. I'm now using next-redux-wrapper and on the client side it's working. But when i access my store in getServerSideProps() it returns the initial state. I checked several examples but i can't get it working.

My configureStore.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import reducer from "./../service";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { createWrapper, HYDRATE} from 'next-redux-wrapper';

const SET_CLIENT_STATE = 'SET_CLIENT_STATE';

const storeEnhancers = typeof window != 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const makeStore = ({ isServer }) => {

  if (isServer) {

    return createStore(reducer, storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)) );

  } else {

      const { persistStore, persistReducer } = require('redux-persist');
      const storage = require('redux-persist/lib/storage').default;

      const persistConfig = {
          key: 'nextjs',
          whitelist: ['userReducer'],
          storage
      };

      const store = createStore(
        persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer),
        storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
      );
  
      store.__PERSISTOR = persistStore(store);

      return store;
  }
};

export const wrapper = createWrapper(makeStore);

export const setClientState = (clientState) => ({
  type: SET_CLIENT_STATE,
  payload: clientState
});
```

My _app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../styles/theme';
import { useStore } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {wrapper} from './../redux/configureStore';

const MyApp = ({Component, pageProps}) => {
  const store = useStore((state) => state);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Deeltuinen</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
      </Head>
        <PersistGate persistor={store.__PERSISTOR} loading={null}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </PersistGate>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

And finally the page where i want to get the store state:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './../../components/Layout';
import API from './../../service/api';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {wrapper, setClientState} from './../../redux/configureStore';

const AccountSettings = ({data}) => {
 
  return (
    <Layout title="Deeltuinen">
      // User form
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  ({store, req, res}) => {
    const state = store.getState();
    console.log(state);

    //const data = await API.getUser(state.userReducer.user.token);
  }
);

export default connect(state => state,{setClientState})(AccountSettings);
```

Comment: getServerSideProps is the pretty much one of the first few functions that run when the page is hit, so how would it contain any other state than the intialState for redux?

Comment: I'm using redux persist to save the store between the pages. I store the user id in the Redux store which i want to use in getServerSideProps.

Comment: Redux persist by default stores the redux state in localStorage, which is a browser implementation and therefore not available on the server side. Unless you have implemented something manually to persist the state server side as well it won't work.

Comment: What's then the best strategy to get the user id and create an server side rendered page with user data?

Comment: @Emke look at the "iron-session" example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/pages/profile-ssr.tsx

Docs: https://github.com/vvo/iron-session

Answer (score 2):

My Code:

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(async ({ req, res, store }) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  console.log('state', state);

  return {
    props: {},
  };
});
`
```

Comment: I'm getting the initial store state, without the values i stored before.

Comment: @Emke did you manage find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookies to store auth credentials and then access it server side using request cookies

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to access the local store, which resides on the browser side, from the server side. You need to find a way to pass it up to the server at your request. By URL parameters or cookies. Or, if you want to use server-side session store (which the lib will anyway use a cookie to track your session), check this link;

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/authenticating

If cookie is just a token to associate server session object and multiple servers are running behind LB without sticky session config, session replication will be required.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`iron-session`](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session) to do exactly what you're looking for and store the user data from your session in Redux. [Check the NextJS example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/pages/profile-ssr.tsx).

```js
import type { IronSessionOptions } from 'iron-session'

type User = {
  isLoggedIn: boolean
  login: string
  avatarUrl: string
}

export const sessionOptions: IronSessionOptions = {
  password: process.env.SECRET_COOKIE_PASSWORD as string,
  cookieName: 'iron-session/examples/next.js',
  // secure: true should be used in production (HTTPS) but can't be used in development (HTTP)
  cookieOptions: {
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  },
}

// This is where we specify the typings of req.session.*
declare module 'iron-session' {
  interface IronSessionData {
    user?: User
  }
}


// In your pages
import { InferGetServerSidePropsType } from 'next'
import { withIronSessionSsr } from 'iron-session/next'

export default function SsrProfile({
  user,
}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {user?.isLoggedIn && <pre>{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = withIronSessionSsr(async function ({
  req,
  res,
}) {
  const user = req.session.user

  if (user === undefined) {
    res.setHeader('location', '/login')
    res.statusCode = 302
    res.end()
    return {
      props: {
        user: { isLoggedIn: false, login: '', avatarUrl: '' } as User,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { user: req.session.user },
  }
},
sessionOptions)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to pass some parameters to the getServerSideProps, you should set up your pages structure to do so.

Example:

If I need to get some credits from a user, and my api needs the "userId" parameter, I would set up my pages like this:

```
pages/credits/[userId].js
```

That way I can access the userId parameter in the getServerSideProps function this way:

```
export async function getServerSideProps (context) {

   const { userId } = context.params
   
   ...
   // API call to get the Credits by userId
}
```